# Converting numbers to dates in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have a large dataset that I'm importing from a txt file that has multiple date variables that are being formatted as number values 20190101, is there a way to assign a date format as part of import? There is no header in the file and I'm assigning names and lengths sample code below.

```
df <- read_fwf("file name", 
                fwf_cols(id = 8,
                         update_date = 8,
                         name        = 35),
                skip = 0)
```

Or is there a way to convert multiple values in one statement vs one at a time?

```
df$update_date <- as.Date(as.character(df$update_date), "%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to convert multiple values in one statement into Dates
(assuming yyyy mm dd). Here we target all columns that end with "date" in their name.

```
library(dplyr)


df <- data.frame(update_date = c(20190101, 20190102, 20190103),
       end_date = c(20200101, 20200102, 20200103))

df %>% mutate_at(vars(ends_with("date")), ~as.Date(as.character(.x),format="%Y%m%d"))
```

You might similarly use

```
mutate_at(vars(starts_with("date"))
```

or

```
mutate_at(vars(c(update_date, end_date)
```

Comment: love the simplicity Chris!